# Programmatically creating text into another file

Tags: c#

I want to create a class with 15 properties for testing purpose. How can I generate text programatically without copying and pasting?

```
public static class MyTestClass
{
    public static string MyTestProperty1
    {
        get
        {
            return "My test1";
        }
    }

    public static string MyTestProperty2
    {
        get
        {
            return "My test2";
        }
    }
<... so on.. >
}
```

Comment: Ehm, just type all of them? I'm not sure I understand; what's wrong with copying and pasting?

Comment: What are you using for the basis of the class?  Do you have an abstract definition somewhere (hardcoded or dynamic)?

Comment: it could be 2K or 3K in future.. so should be able to do it programmatically

Comment: this will eventually be used for testing.. I dont have any abstract definition

Comment: I don't know how to use mocks

Comment: Is it possible to simply create the class as a text file (in another program, with a simple loop) and then load it and compile it?

Comment: I am sincerely curious how this class with several thousand properties is intended to be used -- even just for testing.

Comment: Are all the classes supposed to be the same? Do they vary in some way?

Comment: Just generate the code as text and compile it afterwards?

Comment: Learning to use mocks will be well worth your time, and much easier to support even if you are just using the code for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct your type manually with [`TypeBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx):

```
// read property names from file
string[] propertyNames = { "MyTestProperty1", "MyTestProperty2" };

AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName("Foo");
AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
   .DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Bar");
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = 
   moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyTestClass", TypeAttributes.Public);

foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
{
    PropertyBuilder property = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(
         propertyName,
         System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, 
         typeof(string), 
         null);        
    MethodBuilder getter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
         "get_" + propertyName,
         MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName, 
         typeof(string), 
         Type.EmptyTypes);
    ILGenerator generator = getter.GetILGenerator();
    // generate default value for property
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, propertyName.Replace("Property", " "));
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    property.SetGetMethod(getter);
}

Type type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
```

Now you can use your type:

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
{
    PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    Console.WriteLine(pi.GetValue(obj));
}

dynamic testObj = obj;
Console.WriteLine(testObj.MyTestProperty2);
```

Actually you can go further and specify property names, types, and default values in some configuration file. I leave that to you :)

Answer (score 0):

If the property names and return values are as simple as you are stating you could just write a simple console application which does the following...
*NOTE:  Code not tested.*

```
int numberOfProperties = 15;

IList<string> code = new List<string>();
code.Add("public static class MyTestClass");
code.Add("{");

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProperties; i++)
{
    code.Add("public static string MyTestProperty" + i);
    code.Add("{");
    code.Add("get");
    code.Add("{");
    code.Add("return \"My test\" + i + "";");
    code.Add("}");
    code.Add("}");
}

code.Add("}");

File.AppendAllLines(<path>, code);
```

If it needs to be more complex you could use the C# [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245.aspx).  Using the CodeDOM you could even [compile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655) the code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a code snippet and use it by typing the name followed by 2 tabs. This allows you change the name and type of the property without changing/indenting the rest of the snippet.
For information on creating code snippets and using them, refer to
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Comment: Code snippets would work when only creating 15, but based on one of the comments @dotnet-practitioner wants to do 2K - 3K in the future.